# How to translate from Top to bottom of the screen

Tags: android-animation

I was stuck on make translation animation from Top to Bottom of the screen by using code bellow but when I put 1.0f it's stay at the same location.

```
ant_play_1.animate().translationY(1.0f);
```

Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

translationY is the value the animation is going to move by, so 1.0f is going to move it 1.0f down. So put in a math calculation involving the screen height - the height of the image itself - the height of where the image is in the view, that will move it down to the bottom.

Comment: I am understand your explain, could you please give me some detail in code? I am very predicated for your kindly help sir.
My project, you can see in the youtube by this link: [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLR4gaIo6eU

Comment: I would like to say thank you very much for you advise. Now I got success by using this: //Get Screen H, W
     Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
     Point size = new Point();
  display.getSize(size);
     //final int Screen_Width = size.x;
     final int Screen_Height = size.y;
  ant_play_3.animate().translationY(Screen_Height);